# Retrieving Active Directory Users with no Email address from a certain group in powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting, users, command

I'm trying in powershell to output all AD users from a certain group with no data in the email address field.

I have the following command:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties * | where {!$_.emailaddress} | select-object samaccountname | export-csv c:\email\noemailusers.csv
```

But I'm trying to narrow down the results to only users who are member of a certain group.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the group and get a members list; get the AD user object for each group member; check whether the user has an email address.

```
Get-ADGroupMember $yourgroup | Get-ADUser -Properties mail | where { $_.mail -eq $null }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
If I have multiple groups that are similar, is it possible to grab all of the users from all of them with some sort of wildcard operator, or should I run a separate command for each group?
Thanks again!

Comment: You can run Get-ADGroup with an appropriate filter and then pipe its output into Get-ADGroupMember.